# GUI is not showing up after logging in

Tags: 14.04, gnome

I removed pulseaudio and alsa-base. I think some of the gnome ui packages were dependent on those two and are removed. So now, after a restart, when I log in it goes in and logs out automatically.

What should I install?
Here is a picture of my screen before logging in. Note that the title bar of the wifi connection window is not showing up. I think if I solve this it should resolve the issue.
[image]

Comment: Can you login normally via terminal with Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Comment: Yes. I can login

Comment: How did you remove those packages? Can you please provide the content of `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/term.log`? It would be enough, if you provide the sections, that relate to the package removal, that you mention in your question (look a the time stamps in the log files or search for `alsa-base` and `pulseaudio`).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4FS4jLsG and http://pastebin.com/5T07nWQ2

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling alsa, pulseaudio, and check to make sure gnome-session is installed. If it is, try reinstalling it.

Comment: yeap there are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the missing `pulseaudio` and `alsa-base` packages are the problem, but to reinstall them you can just switch to a TTY at GUI login with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login and run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio alsa-base
```

If you reinstalled them but you fear that some required package could have been removed along with them upon removal and not reinstalled upon reinstallation, run instead:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
```

To install all the possible missing dependancies.

Comment: they are installed

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi See the update

Comment: apt-get install -f didn't do anything. see http://pastebin.com/P6e70Af5

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi So apparently you don't have any missing dependancy, try the following: `sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio alsa-base && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get install pulseaudio alsa-base && sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi The `&& sudo apt-get install -f` part is redundant, just to be sure

Comment: I did it. http://pastebin.com/XAQ30k2G

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi Can't go into chat right now, no try reinstalling unity if you're using unity: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, if this goes wrong I'll try to get to chat later

Comment: did that. Same thing.